# Send data from android app to Server without OnClickListener?

Tags: android, crowdsourcing

I want to build a system based on crowdsoucing.The android app will gather data about the location of  itms and send them to the server. How to post data in android without using onClicklstener? I want the data to be sent in the background automatically

Comment: how often and exactly when do you want this job to be triggered? Once on app start: Put it into your Activity's onCreate and start an AsyncTask (i.e.). If you want this job to be triggered on specific events: Have a look into BroadcastReceiver and maybe into Services too.

Comment: I want it to be trigged every 20 second if  the location is changed.

Comment: Then you want to have a look at android.location.LocationListener. You can find an example here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/location/android-location-based-services-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a background thread for that. You can use `AsyncTask`, or general Java `Thread` class, or ExecutorService with a Runnable.

Problem with AsyncTask is that you can't use more than 1 AsyncTask sub-classes until the first one had been destroyed. And automatically destroying it after it's done is a little complicated.

Instructions on AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Instructions on Java Thread: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

**Safer way with ExecutorService:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html